# WPF giving incorrect size values

Tags: wpf, window, size, width, resolution

I have a WPF application in which I am attempting to take a screen grab of a WindowsFormsHost control. To do this I am doing a Graphics.CopyFromScreen. On most boxes we have tested on this works perfect, however we have one machine that is not grabbing the right size values. The width and height that are given by WPF do not match the actual width and height of the control. When snooping, the incorrect values show for the ActualWidth and ActualHeight of the control as well. Even further, when I snoop the main window (which is maximized), I get an ActualWidth of 1550 and and ActualHeight of 840, but my screen resolution is 1920x1080. I would understand being a few pixels off for borders, margins, etc, but to have WPF tell me my maximized window is 370 pixels shorter in width than the actual screen just doesn't make sense. Can anyone explain this behaviour?

The following is the code being used to capture an image of the control:

```
public static Bitmap CreateBitmapFromVisual(this FrameworkElement target)
{
    Rect bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(target);
    if (bounds.Width == 0 && bounds.Height == 0)
        return null;

    System.Windows.Point p0 = target.PointToScreen(bounds.TopLeft);
    System.Drawing.Point p1 = new System.Drawing.Point((int) p0.X, (int) p0.Y);
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap((int)bounds.Width, (int)bounds.Height);
    Graphics imgGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
    imgGraphics.CopyFromScreen(p1.X, p1.Y, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size((int) bounds.Width, (int) bounds.Height));
    return image;
}
```

Here is an image to better describe what I'm talking about:

[image]

As you can see, snoop is saying that the actualwidth and actualheight of the WindowsFormsHost is 486x336. Any debug information I log says the same thing. However, when I Print Screen and crop to the control in paint, the actual size is 608x423, a sizeable difference.

As a further update, it seems like the width given by wpf is roughly 80% of the actual width. This is true for both the control and the window.

Comment: The ActualHeight and ActualWidth properties are not in pixels, they are in a device independent unit. Also, is the ActualHeight and ActualWidth you are getting greater or smaller than what you expect it to be?

Comment: Smaller. As with the main window example given in the question above, the main window shows 1550 for the ActualWidth, when the width should be quite a bit greater

Comment: can you post your code so I can run it and see if I get the same result?

Comment: When are you calling `CreateBitmapFromVisual`? When you construct the control? The actual control dimensions are affected by things like themes and font enlarging, and the final dimensions are only determined after the control is actually rendered. You have to wait until after the control is drawn to get its screen dimensions.

Comment: The CreateBitmapFromVisual is called well after the control is drawn. Judging from the fact that the entire window is giving an ActualWidth much less than what it should I would say it has less to do with the control itself and more to do with an interaction between the framework and the system

Comment: Your display appears to be running at 120 DPI. The device independent units that `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` are measured in only match up to pixels when your display is running at 96 DPI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at your DPI settings for your display?

To do this go to Control Panel - Display and select Set custom text size (DPI).  In the dialog that opens you will see a scale to percentage.  If it is not set at 100% then try this.  This could be your issue.